# How to unbind Alt + combination in Linux Mint 18.1?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I am on Linux Mint 18.1.

I'm trying to free-up <kbd>Alt</kbd>+combination via changing:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.switch-group
```

value to

```
[]
```

but it didn't help. How to unbind this system shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it!

First see this: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&p=655543#p655476. It explains why custom shortcuts are not working in Mint 14 Cinamon and there is a workaround for this, a working one!

Now, when you restore "Keyboard" settings under System Tools -> System Settings, then simply go there and go to the Shortcuts tab. Then find "Switch windows of an application" and assign a shortcut. By default there is no key assigned so the default one (Alt + `) is used. But if you assign a different shortcut, which does work, then Alt +` is no longer used! That allows you to assign that shortcut to anything else. In my case, I used that as an alternative shortcut for Toggle Scale, which can be set under Cinamon Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard shortcuts tab.

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&p=655543#p655476